# PHP  php csv generator function fails when called for the second time

Tags: php, http-headers

I have written a class for exporting a MySQL table's info. This is the final function that does this successfully:

```
class CSVExport{
private $file_name;
private $csv_data;


public function  collectAllDataFromTable($table,$file_prefix,$date){

    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result){
        die("Query failed ".mysql_error());
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        $i = 0;
        $csv_output = '';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $csv_output .= $row['Field'].",";
            $i++;

        }


    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
    $values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
    while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
        for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
            $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].", ";
        }
        $csv_output .= "\n";
    }


   // return $csv_output;
    $this->file_name = $file_prefix."_".$date;
    $this->csv_data = $csv_output;

} // End "exportAllDataFromTable"  method


public function exportData(){
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
    header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$this->file_name.".csv");

    print $this->csv_data;exit;    

}  // End 'exportData' method




} // End Db_Export
```

But when I call `exportData()` for the second time with different arguments, it doesn't download the file for me.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: What Truth says... also, you are not doing any error checking in your code, so if the database query doesn't work, you are left with a crashing script

Comment: SUGGESTION: look at mysql_field_name() to allow you to drop the first query and also allow you to do a dump of custom queries. http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php You also may want to quote the field values and escape any commas they contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send only one file at a time to the browser*.

Also, you are calling `exit()` at the end of the export, which ends script execution.

<sub>* in theory, there are multi-part responses, but they have no everyday relevance (yet).</sub>

Comment: So impossible export 2 tables info as separate csv files ?

Comment: @user not impossible, but you'd have to rewrite the script so it saves the results to separate files, then shows a HTML page linking to those two files (for example)